# Execute a React js function on d3js event

Tags: d3.js, reactjs

I'm new with react. I need to call a react js function when clicking on a d3js component.

I have a d3js barchart in a react component. In the same component I have this method:

```
handleClick: function(data){
    this.props.onClick(data);
},
```

I need to call this function when clicking on d3js:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
    .on("click", function(d) {
    this.handleClick(); // my react method
   })
```

but this doesn't work. My output in chrome is this:

```
this.handleClick is not a function
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this does not refer to your react-component, when referenced in an anonymous function. In fact, this refers to the context created by the click handler.

This is a common javascript misconception. 
A common way of accessing a specific "this" variable inside another function, is to bind that function to a specific this-object.

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout)
.on("click", function(d) {
    this.handleClick(); // my react method
}.bind(this) )
```

Another alternative is to bind "this" to an external variable, and then use that variable inside your other functions. Often, people call this variable "self" or "that".

```
var that = this;
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout)
.on("click", function(d) {
    that.handleClick(); // my react method
} )
```

Some more info about this and how it works, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **ES6**, just use arrow functions, arrow functions won't make lexical wrapper which cause this problem when using D3 with React, so just simply do:

```
const g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout)
  .on("click", d => {
     this.handleClick(); // my react method
})
```